# docker build taking too long for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, docker

I have this docker file.

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.14
LABEL maintainer="Sagun Devkota"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache mariadb-connector-c-dev build-base mariadb-dev && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /tmp

COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user
ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```

Whenever I run `docker-compose build` then it takes around 800sec to build the image.
But, if I add pandas to my requirements.txt file then it takes around 3000sec to build the image. What is causing this delay?

Comment: Pandas is a large package that takes a long time to install.  You can verify this by creating a virtual environment on your host machine (i.e. not using docker) and installing pandas in that virtual environment.

Comment: I feel like I've seen in other questions that a Debian-based Python image can use precompiled Python wheel packages, but the Alpine image can't use wheels and always has to compile from source.  Does using the non-Alpine `python:3.10` image work better?

Comment: @MarkChackerian It takes 3-4 minutes when I install it in virtual environment.

Comment: As David said, don't use alpine python image - because it won't use precompiled wheels and will have to install from source. If you needs lightweight, use slim python image, but still debian-based. For some explanation check https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/